# migration from Appdynamics to DataDog

Tags: datadog, appdynamics

I am looking for to migrate from appdynamics (SaaS) to DataDog , can anyone provide some insight/steps/documents to achieve this?

Application monitored in Appdynamics should get monitor in DataDog after this migration is completed.
I will also need to create alert/dashboard in datadog.